# xamarin forms - spacing between elements?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I am very very new to xamarin forms and I have created this very basic layout like so:

```
<StackLayout VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
        <!-- Place new controls here -->
        <Label Text="Enter Email Address To Begin" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" TextColor="#FFFFFF" />
        <Entry Keyboard="Email" Placeholder="Email" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" x:Name="Email" WidthRequest="300" />
        <Button Text="Submit" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center" Clicked="OnSubmit" Style="{StaticResource TextColor}" />
    </StackLayout>
```

The elements appear in the middle of the page and look good, except the fact they are bunched together, is there anyways to create some padding or spacing between these elements?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/margin-and-padding

Comment: You need to set some margins to put space in between the controls.

Comment: How do I add margins?

Comment: For each element add the `Margin` property...

Comment: Margin works great!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Spacing property from StackLayout, just like this:

```
<StackLayout VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Spacing="25">
```